# Validation in one place only - in form type classes

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

I want to write a validation for the forms on my website. As far as I know symfony 2 allows a couple of ways to do so:

- annotations
- yaml
- xml
- in entity class

Ok, but my case is that I have a lot of forms on my website, which I create using form type classes (for instance `Project\AcmeBundle\Form\Type\MyFormType`).

So the best way for me would be creating a method inside a form type class handling validation for all its fields. Something like:

```
<?php

namespace Project\AcmeBundle\Form\Type;

class UserType extends FormTypeInterface
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('login', 'text', ['required' => false])
                ->add('password', 'text', ['required' => false]);

        $builder->add('Save', 'submit');
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Project\AcmeBundle\Entity\Users'
        ));
    }

    public function validation()
    {
        // do something here
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }

} // End UserType
```

That would be the first question. I was also curious about disabling all other types of validation - how can I do that?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

For the first question you can use [Callback constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html), here is an example:

```
class MyCustomType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('foo', 'number')
            ->add('bar', 'number')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver
            ->setDefaults(array(
                'data_class' => 'ENTITY',
                'constraints' => array(
                    new Callback(
                        array('callback' => array($this, 'validateForm'))
                    )
                )
            ));
    }

    /**
     * @param $data
     * @param ExecutionContextInterface $context
     */
    public function validateForm($data, ExecutionContextInterface $context)
    {
        if ($data->getFoo() < 100) {
            $context
                ->buildViolation('Invalid Foo.')
                ->atPath('foo')
                ->addViolation()
            ;
        }
    }


    public function getName()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool, thanks! But what if I'd want to use symfony constraints?

Comment: @khernik what constraints?.. Callback is also symfony constraint.